# PHP tag in post content makes wordpress go crazy

Tags: php, posts, tags, html, parse

I am trying to insert `PHP` code in post content, but I've just realized that it brokes Wordpress or maybe some plugin.

As for example

```
avoid any specific class naming structure or style.
<?php 

You can see this simple example at work in this CodePen demo. Resize the window to see the change take place.
```

So in this case `You can see ...` won't be rendered as output.

If `php tag` is closed like this

```
  avoid any specific class naming structure or style.
    <?php 
    // Some code 
    ?>

    You can see this simple example at work in this CodePen demo. Resize the window to see the change take place.
```

I this case everything work just fine...

I also tried to wrap using `pre,cod` and `shortcodes`, but still the same.

I am using the latest version of wordpress. Maybe someone has already faced with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the goal of `<?php \\Some code ?>`? If simply to show the markup, wrapping it in a `<code>` tag should work (depending on your plugins and theme). If you wish to execute the PHP code, it will not ever work without breaking WP.

Comment: Doesn't work. It is doing something weird, I have no idea what happens.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Even `code,pre` .. as I've described in my question. I don't wish to execute code, it is executed automatically or whatever is happened

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the php code to be output without executing it, just escape the `<` signs by replacing it with the html entity `&lt;`.

```
&lt;?php
```

Like this, the tag will not be recognised and will be output as `<?php`.

Comment: This is already done here is formatted code example `<span class="cp">&lt;?php</span>`

Comment: @gzbuaapzroyn Please clarify your question, describing how you are inserting the code into post content and showing the code you use to achieve that. Just showing what you are inserting, leaving away that it already is being escaped, makes us have to do wild guessing